# Import error of node packet in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am having some strange issues when I try to include the node_module angular2-google-maps. I get these errors:

```
angular2-polyfills.js:1243 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    Evaluating http://127.0.0.1:3000/angular2-google-maps/core
    Error loading http://127.0.0.1:3000/public/main.ts
```

I can see that the path is wrong to this url: http://127.0.0.1:3000/angular2-google-maps/core, it should be http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core.js I guess?

I import the package in my component like this:

```
import { ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
```

Which should be right. Have I missed anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [angular2-google-maps](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps) you should check the [example plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YX7W20?p=preview).

See the config.js file, it contains the following

```js
packages: {
  'angular2-google-maps': {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
   }
}
```

That's the part you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also include the bundled file angular2-google-maps.js into a script tag into your HTML entry file:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2-google-maps/bundles/ angular2-google-maps.js"></script>
```

This file is SystemJS-compliant.

See the corresponding documentation:

- https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html#package-installation