# Include JavaScript file inside TypeScript file

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on Angular 2 and I'm trying to include inside a TypeScript (`.ts` file) a `.js` file. The JavaScript file I want to include is a simple google maps file, here it is:

```
<script>
var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8
    });
}
</script>
```

I downloaded the `google-maps.d.ts` declaration file from [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) and I moved this file in the same project (and folder) of my `.ts` file.

So I have a folder with the `.ts`, `.js` and `google-maps.d.ts` inside.

My .ts for completeness looks like:

```
import {Component, Injector, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
/// <reference path="./google-maps.d.ts" />

@Component({
    selector: 'my-map-selector',
    template: `
        <div id="map"></div>  // google map will appear here
    `,
})

export class mymapComponent {

}
```

Now, how do I import the .js file inside .ts? 
I tried with `/// <reference path="./google-maps.d.ts" />` but nothing happened (can't see the map)

Answer (score 1):

In fact a `.d.ts` file only describes the contract of the library but it's not something usable for runtime.

If you want to use Google Maps, you could try the angular2-google-maps library and you need to configure it this way by adding the corresponding JS file:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2-google-maps/bundles/ angular2-google-maps.js"></script>
```

See this question for more details:

- [Import error of node packet in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246291/import-error-of-node-packet-in-angular2/36247123#36247123)

Comment: thank you for having told me about this new solution, now I can see the map on the page. Now i'd like to go a little further and I'd like to have a place searchbox like this one.. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox      It seems that angular-maps doesn't provide this functionality, how can I add the places-searchbox to my app?

Answer (score 0):

To use javascript file in your typescript code, declare it's source path in script tag, download it's .d.ts file(if available), give its path in tsd.d.ts file . use ///reference to use that typing file.

If .d.ts file is not available, declare a variable for that library and use that variable for calling further function.

e.g. to use lodash.js code

1) declare it's .js src path in script tag.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

2) in .ts file, you can use it by declaring a variable. e.g.

```
declare var _:any;
```

See if it works

Regards

Ajay